# Rerenceing HD video file in Jw Player using Jscript

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, jwplayer

How do i add the hd video file in this code? Hd plugin is enabled. I went through their [documentations](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/addons/hd-plugin/12641/hd-plugin-guide). But didn't get how i can achieve it in this code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'></script>

<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var so = new SWFObject('player.swf','mpl','470','320','9');
  so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
  so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
  so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
  so.addVariable('file','sample.mp4');
  so.addVariable('plugins','hd-1');
  so.write('mediaspace');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {
                'file':                 'sd-video.mp4',

                'hd.file':              'hd-video.mp4',
                'hd.state':             'true'
        };
        var params = {

                'allowfullscreen':      'true',
                'allowscriptaccess':    'always',
                'bgcolor':              '#ffffff'

        };
        var attributes = {
                'id':                   'player1',

                'name':                 'player1'
        };
        SWFObject.embedSWF('player.swf', 'flashContent', '300', '250', '9', 'false', flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
```

In my case I can reference hd video like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'></script>

<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var so = new SWFObject('player.swf','mpl','470','320','9');
  so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
  so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
  so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
  so.addVariable('file','sample.mp4');//reference to sd video.
  so.addVariable('hd.file','hd_sample.mp4');//reference to the hd version of video.
  so.addVariable('hd.state','true'); //too choose hd as default.
  so.addVariable('plugins','hd-1');
  so.write('mediaspace');
</script>
```